# Mount external LUKS hard drive

Tags: mount, encryption, luks

I recently updated my laptop's hard drive to a bigger one. The previous one I mounted it in an external case to transform it in to an external drive. The old drive was encrypted with LUKS. When I plug it in it asks me for a passphrase, but when I enter it correctly, I only see the grup related files, and not the files from my LLVM. Is there a way to do this automatically or do I need to follow the process through command line using

```shell
cryptsetup open ...
sudo mkfs.ext4
sudo mount /dev/mapper/'short name in mapper' 'name of dir to mount to'
unmount:
sudo umount /dev/mapper/'short name in mapper' # or sudo umount 'name of dir mounted to'
sudo cryptsetup luksClose 'short name in mapper'
```